# PLSQL , how to store ORA-06512 into some variable?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using flyway for data migration using Jenkins. I want to enable and disable triggers when data correction code is executing.
I managed to handle exception and my enable disable triggers functionality working fine. However I want to print exact line number when exception occurs.
But line number is printed where RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR is called.
How can I store Line number like v_errorMsg is stored? I want to see Exact Line number in script in Jenkins console.

Below is my Sample PLSQL Script executed using flyway.

```
DECLARE
  v_errFlag BOOLEAN := FALSE;
  v_errorMsg VARCHAR(400);
  v_dealId NUMBER;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
      USR.ENABLE_DISABLE_TRIGGERS('disable');
      --Data Correction starts
     -- Success Test
      --SELECT DEAL_ID INTO v_dealId FROM USR.DEAL WHERE ROWNUM=1; 
      -- Error Test
      SELECT DEAL_ID INTO v_dealId FROM USR.DEAL WHERE DEAL_ID=-1; 
      --Data Correction ends
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
          v_errFlag := TRUE;
          v_errorMsg := SQLERRM;
  END;

  BEGIN
        USR.ENABLE_DISABLE_TRIGGERS('enable');
        SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Triggers Enabled');
      IF v_errFlag THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Data Correction Failed :'||v_errorMsg);            
      ELSE 
          SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Data Correction Completed Successfully');
      END IF;
  END;
END;
/
```

Sample output for error scenario

```
ORA-20001: Data Correction Failed :ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace` after `exception when others then`

```
exception when others then
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line( dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace );
    v_errFlag := true;
    v_errorMsg := sqlerrm;
  end;
```

to display the line number where error occured.